# How to find the diameter of a slice of some annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory

[image]

First excuse my bad drawing.
So, Here $\overline{OA} =r,\overline{OB} =2r, \angle{BOE}=\angle{DOE}=\phi, (0<\phi<\pi/2)$. Now I need the 'diameter' of the region shaded in red, where

$\operatorname{diameter}(S)=\sup \{ |x-y|: x,y\in S \}$

for    $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

This is used in the 5th chapter of the 'Fractal Geometry' Book by K.Falconer, inside a proof about non-existence of tangent at almost all points of a s-set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for $1<s<2$. But no explanation is given there and I failed figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Is there some asserted formula, such as $\max(r, 4r\sin\phi)$...?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang : There are some conditions but is there any general way of doing it, like where these conditions will come up naturally as different sub-cases ?

Comment: In the hope it helps, the formula of my first comment is $\max(|D - B|, |D - C|)$. (This is pretty clearly not the actual diameter, but suggests the approach I'd use myself.)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang : Now I understand what you are pointing at. I think this approximation will do the job. Thank you.